# Sparkle Cocoa: My Application is latest but it still showing update prompt. i have checked appcast.xml and everything seems fine

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sparkle

I am using sparkle to update my application. However, I am facing an issue.

here is my appcast.xml

```
<rss xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="1.2">
<channel>
    <title>Sparkle Test App Changelog</title>
    <link>
        http://sparkle-project.org/files/sparkletestcast.xml
    </link>
    <description>Most recent changes with links to updates.</description>
    <language>en</language>
    <item>
        <title>Version 2.0</title>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[...]]>
        </description>
        <pubDate>Sat, 26 Jul 2014 15:20:11 +0000</pubDate>
        <enclosure url="http://techheal.in/mac/testing_techheal.dmg" sparkle:version="2" length="107758" type="application/octet-stream" sparkle:dsaSignature="MCwCFCdoW13VBGJWIfIklKxQVyetgxE7AhQTVuY9uQT0KOV1UEk21epBsGZMPg=="/>
    </item>
</channel>
```

here is the pop that I am getting:
[image]

The issue is that I am running the lastest build however its still showing me that there is an update because of build version

My latest version is : 2
My latest build is : 1

[image]

In xml i have specified my latest version and i do not know from where its taking the build number. Please help

Answer (score 0):

"Build" is the CFBundleVersion.  "Version" is the CFBundleShortVersionString.

These should generally be the same, "build" being internal and "version" being what you show to the users.  This (old but good) article gives you some good info:

http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/08/02/versioning_os_x_apps/

What is happening in your case is that Sparkle is grabbing CFBundleVersion (which is 1) and comparing that to your XML file (which has 2) and thinking you have to upgrade.

Comment: if I am setting Version = 1 and Build = 2. still it asks for an update by showing the latest version is 2(2) and your current version is 1(2). it I keep my build and version same then it works fine. :(

Comment: This may have to do with the heuristic that Sparkle uses to determine your version, but that is mostly moot as semantically it makes no sense for those two fields to have completely different numbers in there.  If you want a version and a build number you can set the build to, say, 2.0.1 and the version to 2.0b1 (the user-friendly version of the same number).